How do I make components available to regular user account in Delphi when installed using admin account?
I recently upgraded my Delphi from 12.1 to 12.2, which required removing and reinstalling. As a result, I had to reinstall my add-on components, including FastReports. I mistakenly ran the installation using "Run as administrator", with which I've ran into problems before. Generally, if I uninstall and reinstall using my regular account, then input the administrator credentials when prompted, all is good.
However, this time I can only see the FastReports components when I start Delphi as an administrator. I went so far as uninstalling everything, including Delphi itself, removing any left-behind FastReports folders and files, and reinstalling (I think I've done this twice), but nothing changes.
I checked with FastReports, and I followed their suggestion to install the components manually. However, even though the components are installed in a folder that is fully accessible to Everyone, and I can pull up the folder in the Add packages dialog, I get the error that "The specified module could not be found." upon selecting any of the packages.
I saw in another post a suggestion of adding the folder to the path. I've done that both in the Delphi library and in the path Environment variable. Nothing has worked. Also, running Delphi regularly as an administrator is not an option.
I'm beyond frustrated and at quite a loss. Any help would be welcome.
Teri

Component registration is stored in the Registry, and different users/admins have different registry keys. You need to run the IDE as a user and then install the components for that user

Also you can't install components just once for "everyone". Each user has to install them for himself separately (because of the registry).

It is possible to fix it by copying the whole set of Delphi registry keys in registry from one user to another (export to file from one user, then import as the other user).

I've tried several times to install the components after starting Delphi using my non-admin credentials, but I get the same error message "The specified module could not be found". I don't know what else it's looking for!

@MatthiasB - THANK YOU! That did it.

@beantreeze you should setup an answer to this post with any extra details.
